# Heating device needs alarm

Tags: power-electronics, temperature, component-selection, heat-protection

I am making a heating device prototype using an M12 battery and a 12 V diesel glow plug.

[image: M12 Battery Pack]

[image: diesel glow plug]

[image: glow plug diagram]

[image: electricoal test 082623]

As you might imagine, heat is a problem. In this case however, because of my set-up, the heat problem I have is actually at the insulation disc and O-ring. I melted one in an extreme test - somewhere around 300°F (I think).

I have I would like to attach a **miniature** temperature sensor (250°F would be perfect) to the body at the hex nut. The sensor would trigger an audible (irritating) alarm. Turning off the device would be a bonus.

I've done a Google search but not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: correct me (not a car expert at all), but the underlying problem is that glow plugs are usually automatically turned off once the motor is chugging along on its own, but you're trying to operate one for a long, continuous time, right?

Comment: Question: would you really want that alarm/shutdown behaviour and heat as quickly and hot as possible all the time, or would you rather achieve a constant temperature that the device can withstand for longer?

Comment: I ask because these glow plugs have all the means to be temperature-regulated: the "regulating coil" in your drawing **is** a temperature sensor! You can observe the temperature by observing the resistance of your plug, no external thermosensor needed. It of course senses close to the tip, which makes sense for a device that's not expected to be on for long; but with a little experimentation, it'd not be hard to control the average power flow into your plug such that the temperature at the base stays tolerable. Note that there's a whole motor block sucking heat away from the tip before it

Comment: …hits the insulator at the base, as well. Another thing that might be heating up your base: That twisted copper cable bears *a lot* of current – probably some 20 A! Make sure it doesn't contribute to the heat problem.

Comment: First, I must say that I am absolutley blown away by this excange. Simply remarkable! Back in my day as an active inventor and product designer information like this was so darn hard to come by.

Comment: Second, Please forgive me if I blunder on how to use this excange. This is my first foray into an exchange like this and I am learning. My first post had to be deleted. I read Marcus Muller's profile and learned a lot. I will try to live up to the standards he outlined.

Comment: Marcus: my research shows that glow plugs have evolved alot over time largely due to environmental concerns. They now often run for extended times for cleaner burns. I'm looking for ~15 minutes on a device that will be used ~25 a year for ~5 years. All very gross estimates. I have run about 15 tests, with no signs of problems.

Comment: Marcus: Thank you for that tip about the heat sucking properties of the engine block. That gives me an idea - heat sink. Also thanks for the tip about the heat inducing bundle of wire on the body. I think what you are saying is make that smaller. Will experiment today.

Comment: Hi Rick, what my (badly worded) point about the heat coming from the copper is: the problem is very likely not the copper itself, but the quality of contact it makes with the plug. Where there's contact resistance, there's heat :) To help that:  there's so-called *ring terminals* and *fork terminals*: Little washers with an attached "tube" that you can crimp onto wire, and then you can connect your cable safely and removably using nuts :) The crimping (quite possible with normal pliers) ensures a large contact area to the metal washer, and so does that being fastened with nuts to the plug.

Comment: Marcus, ah, a loose connection is a hot connection. I get that. Interesting because today's plan is to fabricate a holder for the plug that will make a tight connection.  What you see in the picture of my set up is a proof of concept. Next stage is more of prototyping. May I also ask if I'm responding in a "forum correct" manner? One more question: Can you give me a little insight about vu2nan's edit. I certainly do not mind, but trying to understand the system.

Comment: Marcus, I did some tests today using a small vice grip to make a secure connection, and to act a heat sink. I am no longer worried (and I have many worries) about heat as related to insulation disc. However the device still needs to be removed from the scene  after about 15 minutes (which was coincidently when the disc temperature became an issue). Now I am going on a quest to find a miniature timer and alarm instead.

Comment: I'd tend to implement such a long timer on a cheap microcontroller. Could swat a lot of flies at the same time: alarming, switching on and off, it could supervise battery voltage...

Comment: Thanks Marcus - I'll study up on that.

Comment: Marcus, man I made that a lot harder than it needed to be...but I learned a lot. I finally realized what a delay and a relay were. I've ordered this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07BT25J52/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07TT8WTVD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1

Comment: The currents that glow plug can draw might be a bit much for these relays!

Comment: @Marcus Darn!  I tried very hard to understand the specs. The best I could tell, I was good. I want to learn. Can you tell me the specs that concern you. Is there a way to read the current draw? Please don't give up on me. I am a seasoned product developer. I am on to something big.

Comment: :D the relay says "10A", and I just eyeballed how much current I expect to flow through the the glow plug. A Bosch service manual I found online said, the plug is OK when the resistance reads above 0.5 Ω, and that would mean, on a 12 V battery, that the current would be 12 V / 0.5 Ω = 24 A. Now, that's the *cold* resistance, and it will rise (hence, the current will drop) as the thing gets hot, but it's not safe to assume it will drop quickly enough or below 10 A at all in time before the PCB and the relay get too hot.

Comment: Bummer dude, the delay relay timer and beeper were WAY too big.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t mind it dying when it trips to protect the plastic, a [thermal fuse](https://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/SDF_JUNE_2016.pdf) in series with the glow plug would shut it down.

[image]

You could combine that with something like a comparator (or comparator-connected op-amp) + Wheatstone bridge driving a beeper with internal circuit if you want a pre-cutoff audible alarm.